# A complex involving an infinite direct sum

Tags: abstract-algebra, direct-sum

Let $A,B_i,C$, for $i \in I$ an infinite index set, be abelian groups such that we have group homomorphisms
$$r_i: A \rightarrow B_i, \,\,\, s_i: B_i \rightarrow C$$
and a complex
$$A \xrightarrow{\bigoplus r_i} \bigoplus _{i \in I}B_i \xrightarrow{\sum s_i} C,$$
that is, $\mathrm{Im}(\bigoplus r_i) \subset \mathrm{Ker}(\sum s_i)$. Since $\bigoplus_{i \in I}B_i$ is an infinite direct sum, each element is a tuple $(b_i)_{i}$ such that $b_i = 0$ for all but finitely many $i$. Hence the sum $\sum s_i$ gives a well-defined element of $C$.

However, does it *necessarily* follow that the map $r_i:A \rightarrow B_i$ is zero for all but finitely many $i$? Is it possible that we have infinitely many nonzero $r_i$ but yet every $a \in A$ maps to an element $(b_i)_i$ such that $b_i = 0$ for all but finitely many $i$?

Comment: Let $A$ be $\mathbb Z^{(\mathbb N)}$, and for each $i$ in $\mathbb N$ let $r_i:A\to\mathbb Z$ be the projection onto the $i$th coordinate. None of these maps is zero, but on each element they are almost all zero.

Comment: (Notice that C and the maps s_i play no role in your question)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Nice thank you, so in this case $A$ is itself an infinite direct sum? Do you think we can do away with it and still get a counterexample?